# Focus lost in IE when element is set to hidden and then visible in the same function

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom, focus

We have a piece of code that sets a container element's visibility to `hidden`, do something to its children, then set the visibility back to `visible`. It works well in Modern browsers, but in IE the input elements inside the container lose focus after execution.

To demo this situation, say we have:

```
<div id="container">
  <input id="input"/>
</div>
```

if you do:

```
var containerEl = document.getElementById('container');
var inputEl = document.getElementById('input');
inputEl.focus();
containerEl.style.visibility = 'hidden';
containerEl.style.visibility = 'visible';
```

The input element is in focus in Chrome. It loses focus in IE.

See [This Demo](https://codepen.io/mjss/pen/aGjgvL)

I am using latest Chrome66 and IE11 when testing.

So, why

```
containerEl.style.visibility = 'hidden';
containerEl.style.visibility = 'visible';
```

makes the focused input lose its focus in IE?

Comment: How about moving the line setting the focus at the end of the function ..?

Comment: @Teemu But my issue is that in IE the originally focused input element loses focus after visibility set to hidden then back to visible (in the same function). Clearly there are some differences in handling style editing execution between IE and modern browsers.

Comment: What I've said  above is a solution to your problem described in the question ... Yes there are differences, there are differences also between "modern browsers". But you didn't ask about differences, actually you didn't ask anything ...

Comment: @Teemu Sorry maybe I wasn't clear about my question... Edited my question to make it clear

Comment: Because IE is designed to behave that way. How/why would someone at SO specifically know "_why_ " ..? Only MS developers can know the answer considering IE is not an open source software.